# Better way of writing this query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I'm wondering if I could replace the below with a join and reduce the need for the ISNULL wrapped around the whole select?

```
SELECT ISNULL(
(
 SELECT Locale FROM Users WHERE UserGuid = @UserGuid),
 (SELECT Locale FROM Companies WHERE CompanyGuid = 
   (SELECT CompanyGuid FROM UserCompany WHERE UserGuid = @UserGuid)
 ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be the equivalent:

```
SELECT ISNULL(u.Locale, c.Locale)
FROM Companies c
INNER JOIN UserCompany uc ON c.CompanyGuid = uc.CompanyGuid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u ON uc.UserGuid = u.UserGuid
WHERE uc.UserGuid = @UserGuid
```

Note: this assumes the UserGuid is unique in Users and UserCompany.

Comment: The only real difference I can see is that the OP's query will always return a row, even if `@UserGuid` does not match anything in either table.  Whether thats important, or even relevant, is hard for us to tell...